# Does an elegant solution exist for this trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I'm trying to solve this:

$\cos ^{-2}x + A\tan{x} = B$

Wolfram alpha spits out an incredibly long and convoluted solution for x.

Is there no simple, straightforward analytical way to solve this?

Comment: Some people find $cos^{-2}(x)$ ambiguous: you probably intend the square of the reciprocal rather than the square of the inverse or the double application of the inverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $\cos^{-2} x=\sec^2 x=1+\tan^2 x$. So we get a quadratic equation in $\tan x$. Solve for $\tan x$ using the Quadratic Formula.

To get $x$, use the $\arctan$ function, remembering that if $x$ is a solution of the equation, then so is $x+n\pi$ for any integer $n$.

**Remark:** I do not think the solution above qualifies as *elegant*. The more appropriate term is *mechanical*. There probably is no elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

$$1+\tan^2 x+A\tan x=\cos^{-2}x + A\tan{x} = B$$
$$(\tan x) ^2 + A\tan{x} + (1 - B) = 0$$
$$\tan x = \text{two solutions of quadratic equation}$$
$$x=\arctan(\cdots)$$